# Matlab OOP calling get method on save for transient property.

Tags: oop, matlab, save, transient

I'm trying to implement a class with a property that can be possibly provided to the constructor or possibly generated in some other method. I don't want the data saved to disk or generated on load. What I have so far is:

```
classdef MyClass
        properties(GetAccess = public, SetAccess = private)
            Property1
            Property2
            Property3
        end
        properties(Access = private)
            Property4
        end
        properties(Transient = true)
            ProblemProperty
        end
        properties(Dependent = true, Transient = true)
            Property5
        end

        methods
            function MyClass
                % Constructor.
            end

            function val = get.Property5(B)
                val = SomeFunction(Property1);
            end

            function val = get.ProblemProperty(B)
                if isempty(B.ProblemProperty)
                    B = GenerateProblemProperty(B);
                end
                val = B.ProblemProperty;
            end

            function B = GenerateProblemProperty(B)
                B.ProblemProperty = AnotherFunction(B.Property2);
            end
        end
    end
```

The problem is that when I try to save the object to disk, Matlab calls the get.ProblemProperty method (confirmed by running the profiler on just the save statement). The ProblemProperty field is empty and I want it to stay that way. It doesn't call the get.Property5 method.

How do I avoid the call to get.ProblemProperty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the property can sometimes be set (i.e. in the constructor) then this property is not strictly dependent. One solution is to store the settable value in a private property (`CustomProblemProperty` in the example below) in the constructor. The `get` method of `ProblemProperty` would then check return this private property value if it's not empty and otherwise return the generated value.

```
classdef MyClass
    properties(GetAccess = public, SetAccess = private)
        Property1
        Property2
        Property3
    end
    properties(Access = private)
        Property4
        CustomProblemProperty
    end
    properties(Dependent = true, Transient = true)
        ProblemProperty
        Property5
    end

    methods
        function B = MyClass(varargin)
            if nargin == 1
               B.CustomProblemProperty = varargin{1};
            end
        end

        function val = get.Property5(B)
            val = SomeFunction(Property1);
        end

        function val = get.ProblemProperty(B)
            if isempty(B.CustomProblemProperty)
               val = AnotherFunction(B.Property2);
            else
               val = B.CustomProblemProperty;
            end
        end

    end
end
```

Comment: I thought about this but sometimes the value is actually provided in the constructor directly. Am I able to set a value for a dependent property in a constructor?

Comment: @MatlabSorter - I updated my answer to allow an optional custom value passed to the constructor. The gist is to use a private property to store this optional value and get.ProblemProperty to decide whether to retrieve this private property or generate a new value.

Comment: @b3 Thanks, I think that should do it. I would like to understand why Matlab makes the call in my implementation, so I'll leave the question open for a little while longer.

Comment: CustomProblemProperty needs to be transient otherwise it will be written to disk.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is working, but it is not the OOP spirit, you are mixing accessors which are the outside shape of the object with what is inside.

I would advise the following

```
classdef simpleClass
    properties(Access = private)
        % The concrete container for implementation
        myNiceProperty % m_NiceProperty is another standard name for this.
    end
    properties(Dependent)
        % The accessor which is part of the object "interface"
        NiceProperty
    end

    method
        % The usual accessors (you can do whatever you wish there)
        function value = get.NiceProperty(this)
            value = this.myNiceProperty;
        end
        function set.NiceProperty(this, value)
            this.myNiceProperty = value;
        end
    end
end
```

NiceProperty is then never saved anywhere and you have the benefit of writing standard code.